# How to get data of atleast one id match using linq query in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dropdown of multiselect where I am sending comma separted multiple values to controller in c# where I am spliting the comma seperated values and sending to linq query. But here I have one probelm i.e I have girlLevelId=2,4,5 in database but I am sending 1,2 values with split but I'm unable to get data of matching value of 2. If I am sending 2,4 then I am retriving data but when I am sending 1,2 I need get data of alteast one match that is 2.

This is my split code and linq query:

```
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(girlLevelId) && IsGirlLevelSearchable)
{
  string[] values = girlLevelId.Split(',');
  for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
  {
    var girlLevelValueId = values[i].Trim();
    query = query.Where(p =>
                        (IsCategorySearchable &&
                            (p.GirlLevelID.Contains(girlLevelValueId)))
                        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `for loop` , you can simply use `.Any()` as follows

```
string[] values = girlLevelId.Split(',');
query = query.Where(p =>IsCategorySearchable && 
                    values.Any(v => p.GirlLevelID.Contains(v.Trim()))
                                        );
```

Comment: I think that should be `values.Any(v => p.GirlLevelID.Contains(v))`.

Comment: how can we use girlLevelValueId if we not use any loop @Ehsan Ullah Nazir

Comment: Its same as you are doing `var girlLevelValueId = values[i].Trim();`

Comment: Your Value array actually contains `girlLevelValueId` so we can use `.Any()`

Comment: i have one doubt here "v" means wht?

Comment: You can set it what ever you want , it can be your name as well :) like    `values.Any(kumar=> p.GirlLevelID.Contains(kumar.Trim())`

Comment: look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: Yeah , exactly .You looked it closely :)